# Using WPF, how do you change color of a cell based on its value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Looks like this question has been asked a few times, but none of the answers fit my scenario...

I'm using a grid, and the ItemsSource is a custom struct named Record.

[image]

How do I check the value of each cell and change the color based on its value? I see answers for this in XAML, but I'd like to handle all the logic in C#. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are not able to adapt the existing answers that provide XAML, you do not understand WPF enough.

Comment: @H.B. I concede that I'm still struggling with XAML, but this is a good way to start learning...

Comment: HB is right, you should try to stick to things that are right rather than things that you understand, this will increase your learning. and trust me it aint that difficult at all, try it out and we are here to help

Comment: look for CellStyles and datatriggers....

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still a xaml only solution but suggesting you the right thing here -

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PROPERTY_NAME}" Value="DESIRED_VALUE">
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

also to mention that in some cases you might need a value converter.

Where you are adding new column in code, you can apply style there like this

```
var style = new Style();

        var dataTrigger = new DataTrigger
        {
            Binding = new Binding("PROPERTY_NAME"),
            Value = DESIRED_VALUE
        };

        dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter
        {
            Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
            Value = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red")
        });

        style.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);




public void create_columns()
    {

       var col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
       col1.Header = "Station";
       col1.Binding = new Binding("Station");


      col1.CellStyle = style;

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: TargetType = "DataGridCell"
Can you explain what that is? I don't have a variable called DataGridCell, is this something hard coded?

Comment: Alright, one last thing. The above code turns the whole ROW a certain color, and not just the cell.... any ideas?

Comment: if you show your code now, I might help you for that

Comment: Thank you!

[XAML](http://pastebin.com/WpQ4StTx) // 

[C#](http://pastebin.com/W1WQmswc)

Comment: instead of applying cell style to DataGrid.CellStyle. you can apply it on Column.CellStyle 
Applying it on grid level applies it on all cells

Comment: I get "the attachable property CellStyle was not found in type Column"

http://pastebin.com/HipKE1ux

Comment: cant see any column code in xaml you pasted but see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

there is cell style on column

Comment: Because I don't have any column code? I really don't know what I'm doing in XAML... I'm starting to make sense of it, but still very much lost. 

The link you sent me is for C#, I thought we'd be changing the style based off a trigger in XAML?

Comment: if you are using AutoGeneratedColumns, you can catch column auto generated event and set style there , but this has to be done in code behind

Comment: Ok, well, I think I'm moving over to Winforms, this is much too complicated. Thanks anyway!

Comment: it is not, do not go back my advice this is as simple and as flexible as it can get..

Comment: I'm sorry, and I don't mean to be rude, but I just don't understand how to implement what you're telling me.

Comment: No prob bud, I have added more code just to explain how can you use it